# How to display the name of the clicked button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

They are working on the game of paper, stone, scissors. I would like to display its id in Result component after pressing one of the buttons. How can I do this?

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.scss";
import SubmitInfo from "./SubmitInfo";
import ResultInfo from "./ResultInfo";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.test = this.test.bind(this);
  }

  test = id => {
    //return <Result id={this.props.id}></Result>
    console.log("test");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="board">
          <div className="title_row">
            <h1 className="title">Kamień, Papier, Nożyce</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="board">
          <div className="submit_row">
            <SubmitInfo id="papier" click={this.test} />
            <SubmitInfo id="kamien" click={this.test} />
            <SubmitInfo id="nozyce" click={this.test} />
            <ResultInfo id={this.test} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**SubmitInfo.js**

Transfer to id props and click event, Then I render three buttons with different icons.

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "./submit.scss";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faHandPaper,
  faHandScissors,
  faHandRock
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import ResultInfo from "./ResultInfo";

function Submit({ id, click }) {
  if (id === "nozyce") {
    return (
      <button className="submit" onClick={click}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon" icon={faHandScissors} />
      </button>
    );
  } else if (id === "papier") {
    return (
      <button className="submit" onClick={click}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon" icon={faHandPaper} />
      </button>
    );
  } else if (id === "kamien") {
    return (
      <button className="submit" onClick={click}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon" icon={faHandRock} />
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default SubmitInfo;
```

**ResultInfo.js**

Here I would like to display the id of the button clicked.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ResultInfo extends Component {
  render(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        {" "}
        {this.props.id}
        {console.log(this.props.id)}
      </div>
      //<div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default ResultInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use *state*. Initialize it in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    id: null,
  };
}
```

Your test function, should set the state with the id

```
test = id => {
  this.setState({
    id,
  });
};
```

ResultInfo component should recieve the state id as an attribute

```
<ResultInfo id={this.state.id} />
```

And, the buttons on SubmitInfo component should call the click function, with the id as a parameter

```
<button className='submit' onClick={() => click(id)}>Rock</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

David's explanation is correct.

I was working on a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-thunder-l2vnw) on parallel, figured it'd help.

You have some additional errors, like exporting default `SubmitInfo` instead of `Submit`, and you can use conditional rendering of `ResultInfo` component.